# Why does D3.js not display my geoJSON file ?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization, geojson

## I want to draw the outline of Berlin (germany) with D3.js.

The geoJSON file for Berlin i use is this (there Berlin-"bundesländer"):
http://opendatalab.de/projects/geojson-utilities/

But it just doesn't work with my .json file. I cant spot the difference to this .json file for us-states that works just fine with exactly the same code:
http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_12/us-states.json

I also tried to completely copy the us-states file, delete all "features" entries except one and then only replace the coordinates-array of the one left with the coordinates-array of my file. But firebug tells me that the path's element has no "d" attribute at all.

**I really appreciate any hint. Thank you in advance!**

/*
         I use the default albersUsa projection.
         If I define path as : d3.geo.path().projection(null) some path-element is added.
         But if that's the solution how can i translate that path ?
          */

```
    var path = d3.geo.path();

    d3.json("data/berlinBundeslaender_simplify2000.json",function(geoJson){

        var color1 = d3.scale.category20();

        mainSVG.selectAll("path")
        .data(geoJson.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d",path)
            .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color1(i);});
    });
```

Comment: Might be better to use a jsfiddle to show us what's not working.

Comment: Don't use the albersUSA projection. It will clip anything outside the US.

Comment: Thank you Lars! That solved my problem!  Also thank you Andy, next time i will consider to use jsfiddle, i didnt know it.

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The albersUSA projection will clip anything that's not within the lower 48 US states, Hawaii or Alaska. That is, anything else simply won't be displayed. Use a different projection for different parts of the world.